# As as VS Though

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> As cute as the dog may have looked, they refused to let him inside their house.
>
> Though the dog may have looked cute, they refused to let him inside their house.

What's the difference here? Thank you.

Comment: No real difference in meaning. The first has a little more flair. The second is prosaic. The first *suggests* that the dog's cuteness *may* already have been mentioned. The second doesn't suggest that.